# Is there an equivalent of ArcGIS Hyperlink script editor in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, vbscript, hyperlink, actions

I am trying to find similar functionality in QGIS to ArcGIS Hyperlink script editor.

In ArcGIS I can parse VBScript from a selected field in an attribute table. The script would execute on mouse click.

[ArcGIS 10.1 Hyperlinks help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000004000000)

Can I achieve the same task in QGIS using VBScript?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware about using VBScript in QGIS as Python tends to be more commonly used. But yes, there is a similar functionality. You can set up **Actions** in QGIS, by using Python or shell commands, to perform certain tasks for specific fields:

[image: Actions]

You can access these **actions** when using *Identify Features* which will provide you with the list of **actions** you set up. If you want to run an action with a simple mouse-click, the [**Hotlink**](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Hotlink/) plugin allows you to do just that.

[Here](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/create_vector_data/actions.html) is some additional information about **actions**.

**EDIT**:

After clicking *Insert expression*, you can specify fields/values of that particular layer by accessing the list:

[image: Fields/values]

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I have had a look at the Actions functions. Where can I specify the desired fields [Value] in the expression. Also I am not certain of how to configure an execute script function.

Comment: No problem @roesa9! If you're wanting advice on how to create a script function then it may be best to ask a [new](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) question and describe what you want your action to do. Hopefully others will offer expert advice.

Comment: Ooops, forgot to mention that I edited my post on how to specify fields/values in the expression :)